# Upload local repository to assembla

Tags: svn, assembla

I am trying to add my project folder to a local repository, then upload it to assembla using Turtoise SVN. Here are the steps I took.

1. Create a new folder named SVN, right click, TurtoiseSVN -> Create a repository here
2. Create folder structure -> Start Repobrowser
3. Right click the trunk folder -> Add folder -> Browse to my project
   folder -> Select folder
4. Right click at the SVN folder -> tortoiseSVN -> import -> `URL of my space`

When I check out, I get the same repository, but what I want to do is to specify a trunk,  branch and add new features later. The folder structure is not branchs, tags, trunks but there are locks, confs, db,... The commit tab in assembla shows me empty trunk, branch and tags too!

I also want to write the code and commit directly to assembla, ignoring my local repository.

Please specify step by step action or link, I tried Googling but there is not any promising!

Thank you and best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subversion is a centralized repository system.  That means, whenever you commit to it, you are committing to the hosted repository you have on Assembla.

It seems that you are looking at a locally hosted svn repository if you see "locks, confs, db" as your folder structure.  You should be seeing the folder structure that you see in your Assembla Code browser.

You only need to checkout the repository from Assembla to start working, here is a rather outdated video to help you, though it still shows you how to properly connect tortoisesvn to Assembla: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IWgTyOOufow

Answer (score 0):

> I also want to write the code and commit directly to assembla, ignoring my local repository.

You cannot use two repositories in a single subversion working copy.

Your question indicates that your are not very familiar with Subversion, please read the [book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/). That will also answer the question about the folder structure.

Comment: What do you mean you cannot use two repositories in a single subversion working copy?  I can have external references.

Comment: The questions sounds more like the OP wanted to commit the same directories to different repositories, like you can do in `git`.

Answer (score 0):

1. You imported wrong folder into Assembla's repo on step 4
2. Even if you used correct folder (project's folder with sources), you can't use single Working Copy for committing into **unrelated repositories**

As final note:

You selected wrong tool (use CVCS in DVCS style is bad idea), use wrong methods and in wrong order.

*Theoretically* you **can** have and support two mirros of data in two repos (local and remote), but: with some tricks and you **must** re-made **all from scratch**

Comment: I am unaware that I am doing it in DVCS style. If I understand your idea correctly, deleting local repos then sync it with remote repo means that I have to start from scratch rigth?

Comment: @MinhTriet - you have to start from scratch, yes. But you must to re-done all correctly - it isn't only deleting *remote repository*, but **more** tricks